# Refrigerator seems to run continuously (or very long times)

Tags: refrigerator

It's a beko CRF4800. The coils get hot and it runs for 40 minutes straight, resting for around the same time. It makes quite a loud buzzing noise, I think something is up with the fridge. I've already tried:

Cleaning the refrigerator coils and compressor completely from dust

Unplugging and melting it for 12 hours

Adding a layer of petroleum jelly to the gaskets so it would insulate better and cold air couldn't go out

Is it OK to remove the Vaseline now?

It started just buzzing like insane and running for about 1h30min after I added that jug of water into the deep freezer like I was told it's supposed to decrease run time... The deep freezer doesn't get used in our house, so it just runs without a purpose. I was told that it's better than "cooling volumes of air"

It also makes a bubbly or a wave noise when it's running and seems like it's "breathing" for some time after the compressor stops running

The temperature setting is on the very warmest, it still cools the food like a normal fridge with that setting, which is awesome (6C max in the freezer) but it hums all the time.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, remove the jelly. Refrigeration systems aren't really user-serviceable. It sounds like the compressor is failing. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you understand how this site works. We're not a discussion forum.

Comment: Maybe it's just a bad gasket? How do you know if the compressor is failing? Maybe it's failing because of the damn jelly?

Comment: "It makes quite a loud buzzing noise...." "It started just buzzing like insane...." "It also makes a bubbly or a wave noise when it's running...."

Comment: What can I do to get most out of this compressor now?

Comment: Definitely remove the Vaseline/Jelly?

Comment: Your issue isn't the seal. Refrigerators run for decades, so you could leave the door wide open for a week and it shouldn't make the kind of noise you describe.

Comment: sounds like the "freon" is low if you hear bubbling.

Comment: The buzzing could be the relay for the compressor, these do go bad but the noises other than that and a long run time could point at an undercharge.

Comment: So just as Joe Fala stated, not enough freon/coolant? The bubbly noise in the coils could indicate it's liquid instead of gas? And thanks. How do I fix if it's running at liquid?

Comment: Found an interesting article. Here it states that for a compressor and gas to overheat, it must be around 350F. It's good to keep the refrigerator below 225F: https://www.achrnews.com/articles/137329-seven-signs-of-low-refrigerant-in-a-system

Comment: My mother replaced the seal on her fridge and it went from slightly buzzing to inaudible. We literally wondered that it runs like a new fridge. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

If it's "bubbling" while it's running it could indicate improper charge. A refrigerant system should have liquid at the metering device. If there is still vapour in the mixture(saturation temperature) then you are loosing capacity which would explain the long run times. It doesn't mean there is a leak it just means that it's not running at full capacity.

In this image the metering device is an expansion valve. [image]www.wikipedia.com

It gets pretty complicated but to aid you in your search for the problem if something you try makes the bubbling sound go away you may be on the right track. Keep in mind any changes to system take about 15 minutes to stabilize. Sometimes just pulling the fridge away from the wall does the trick. With fridge has bubbling often indicates too much heat overall in the system.

Comment: Is it good to keep the refrigerator at warmer temperatures to keep the compressor running for more years? (and not fail)

Comment: Joe Fala so what do I need to do?

Comment: The coil at the back needs to dissipate heat. I'd start by pulling the fridge out from the wall and see if it resolves.

Comment: Thanks. I always make sure there's a ton of room between the wall and the refrigerator coils! In total around 10cm

Comment: It could simply have a leak. But the things you have tried and pulling it out are free, so it's best to try them before replacing it. The fridge being too full restricting air flow inside usually would have the opposite effect but still worth a shot. Make sure the items inside are not all the way to the back of the fridge.

Comment: A deep space between the wall and the refrigerator doesn't really fix it though (around 10cm space) I pulled. Feeling as if whatever I do the problem gets actually worse. It was mostly fixed before I melted the damn fridge!

Comment: Also the defrost timer could be stuck in the on position but that would normally disable the compressor, still worth looking into if the other stuff doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to run a little shorter after removing that Vaseline. It appears to make that noise right after the compressor turns off (liquids sound in the coils, wave sounds) and sounds like crackling while it's on

Comment: Edit: seems to run A LOT shorter. The wave sounds are still there and the liquid sounds, the wave sounds I can hear to another room

Comment: The wave sounds after the compressor shuts off is somewhat normal. It's just the refrigerant moving around and equalizing pressure

Comment: Is it normal for it to run 30-40 minutes and then shut of for another 40?

Comment: I'd say 30-40 minutes is relatively normal. If your house is hot or humid it'll run longer too. If the bubble sound is gone and the temperature in the fridge is good I'd say your okay.

Comment: Now it just seemed to start running what seems to be hours. I'll count though, but it seems like it's humming all the time, and I'm worried about the fridge. The temperature setting is on the very warmest (1 out of 7) that cools the food just fine (6C max) but it still seems to run all the time